# import local package over global package

Tags: python-2.6, centos6

I'm working on a support library for a large Python project which heavily uses relative imports by appending various project directories to `sys.path`.

Using [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/) as a template I attempted to create a package structure which will allow me to do a local install, but can easily be changed to a global install later if desired.

One of the dependencies of my package is the [`pyasn1` package](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/) for the encoding and decoding of ASN.1 annotated objects. I have to include the `pyasn1` library separately as the version supported by the CentOS 6.3 default repositories is one major version back and has known bugs that will break my custom package.

The top-level of the library structure is as follows:

```
MyLibrary/
  setup.py
  setup.cfg
  LICENSE.txt
  README.txt
  MyCustomPackage/
  pyasn1-0.1.6/
```

In my setup configuration file I define the install directory for my library to be a local directory called `.lib`. This is desirable as it allows me to do absolute imports by running the command `import site; site.addsitedir("MyLibrary/.lib")` in the project's main application without requiring our engineers to pass command line arguments to the setup script.

*setup.cfg*

```
[install]
install-lib=.lib
```

*setup.py*

```
setup(                                                                          
   name='MyLibrary',
   version='0.1a',
   package_dir = {'pyasn1': 'pyasn1-0.1.6/pyasn1'},   
   packages=[
             'MyCustomPackage',         
             'pyasn1',
             'pyasn1.codec',
             'pyasn1.compat','
              pyasn1.codec.ber',
             'pyasn1.codec.cer',
             'pyasn1.codec.der',
             'pyasn1.type'
            ],
   license='',
   long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
   data_files = []
)
```

The problem I've run into with doing the installation this way is that when my package tries to import `pyasn1` it imports the global version and ignores the locally installed version.

As a possible workaround I have tried installing the `pyasn1` package under a different name than the global package (eg `pyasn1_0_1_6`) by doing `package_dir = {'pyasn1_0_1_6':'pyasn1-0.1.6/pyasn1'}`. However, this fails since the imports used internally to the `pyasn1` package do not use the `pyasn1_0_1_6` name.

**Is there some way to either a) force Python to import a locally installed package over a globally installed one or b) force a package to install under a different name?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)  to ensure that your application runs in a fully known configuration which is independent from the OS version of libraries.

EDIT: a quick (unix) solution is setting the [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable, which works just like `PATH` for Python modules (module loaded from first path in which is found, so simply append you directory at the beginning of the `PYTHONPATH`). Anwyay, **I strongly recommend you to proceed with `virtualenv`**, since it was specifically engineered for handling situations like the one you are facing.

## Rationale

The process is easily automatable if you write a [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) script specifying dependencies with `install_requires`. For a complete example, refer to [this one I wrote](https://github.com/esseks/bitsd/blob/master/setup.py)

## Setup

Note that you can easily insert the steps below in a `setup.sh` shell script.

First create a virtualenv and enter it:

```
$ virtualenv $name
$ cd $name
```

Activate it:

```
$ source bin/activate
```

Now `cd` to your project directory and run the installer script:

```
$ cd $my_project_dir
$ python ./setup.py --prefix $path_to_virtualenv
```

Note the `--prefix $path_to_virtualenv`, which is used to tell the script to install in the virtualenv instead of system-wide. Call this **after activating the virtualenv**. Note that all the depencies are automatically downloaded and installed in the virtualenv.

Then you are done. When you want to leave the virtualenv, issue:

```
$ deactivate
```

On subsequent calls, you will only need to activate the virtualenv (step 2), maybe using a `runawesomeproject.sh` if you really want.

As noted on the virtualenv website, you should use virtualenv >= 1.9, as the previous versions did not download dependencies via HTTPS. If you consider plain HTTP to be sufficient, then any version should do.

You might also try relocatable virtualenvs: setup it and copy the folder to your host. Anyway, note that *this feature is still experimental*.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond - I've been stuck on this for a couple of days and appreciate the help. My concern with this solution is that it may place a burden on the users to properly setup and activate a virtual environment on their production machines to run the program. Is there a relatively simple way to script the install, creation and use (sourcing) of a virtual environment?

Comment: This doesn't solve my particular problem, but I think it's a reasonable answer given the scope of the question.